# Is it necessary to distinguish 3 state fields when doing breadth first search

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

In the CTCI solution for checking to see if there is a route between two nodes, a 3 state enum is defined. However, it appears that what is really important is a binary state of (visited = true|false). Is this true? If not, why is it necessary to distinguish between 3 separate states?

```
public enum State {
        Unvisited, Visited, Visiting;
} 

public static boolean search(Graph g,Node start,Node end) {  
        LinkedList<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
        for (Node u : g.getNodes()) {
            u.state = State.Unvisited;
        }
        start.state = State.Visiting;
        q.add(start);
        Node u;
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            u = q.removeFirst();
            if (u != null) {
                for (Node v : u.getAdjacent()) {
                    if (v.state == State.Unvisited) {
                        if (v == end) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            v.state = State.Visiting;
                            q.add(v);
                        }
                    }
                }
                u.state = State.Visited;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: In this case if you want to know just if route exists using BFS then I think it is not necessary to have State.Visiting, however that state might help in other cases such as finding a cycle.

Comment: The only read of the state is in `if (v.state == State.Unvisited)`, so of course a boolean would suffice.

Comment: `Visiting` is not needed for the search. It is sometimes used for other purposes (like graphic display of the search) which are not directly related to the search.